# Make code restart itself after failed log in attempts?

Tags: python

So Im very new to python and Im creating a menu just to practice a little. So I gave the user 3 attempts to write the correct username and password, but then after the last failed attempt I want them to be sent back to the "menu" again (aka the first part of the code itself). How would one do this in the cleanest way possible? Im very new at this so I dont know alot about coding so all the solutions Ive found so far seem very complicated to me...

```py
print("=========MENU=========")
print("1.Login")
print("2.Exit")
nav = int(input())
if (nav) == 1:
    print("=========LOGIN=========")
    print("PLEASE IMPUT THE CORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
    print("YOU HAVE 3 ATTEMPTS")
    count=0
    while count < 3:
        username = input("USERNAME: ")
        password = input("PASSWORD: ")
        if username == "admin" and password == "password" :
            print("ACCESS GRANTED")
            break
        else:
            print("WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD COMBO")
            print("TRY AGAIN")
            count += 1
    if count == 3:
        print("NO ATTEMPTS LEFT")
        print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN")
        break
if (nav) == 2:
    print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN...")
    exit()
```

Comment: Look into finite state machine. Might be a better way for you to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script inside an infinite loop like this:

so the only way to stop your program programmatically by choosing exit command

```
while True:
    print("=========MENU=========")
    print("1.Login")
    print("2.Exit")
    nav = int(input())
    if (nav) == 1:
        print("=========LOGIN=========")
        print("PLEASE IMPUT THE CORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
        print("YOU HAVE 3 ATTEMPTS")
        count=0
        while count < 3:
            username = input("USERNAME: ")
            password = input("PASSWORD: ")
            if username == "admin" and password == "password" :
                print("ACCESS GRANTED")
                break
            else:
                print("WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD COMBO")
                print("TRY AGAIN")
                count += 1
        if count == 3:
            print("NO ATTEMPTS LEFT")
            print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN")
    if (nav) == 2:
        print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN...")
        exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer

Answer (score -1):

One option might be to make a recursive function, and use main:

```py
def main():
    print("=========MENU=========")
    print("1.Login")
    print("2.Exit")
    nav = int(input())
    if (nav) == 1:
        print("=========LOGIN=========")
        print("PLEASE IMPUT THE CORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
        print("YOU HAVE 3 ATTEMPTS")
        count=0
        while count < 3:
            username = input("USERNAME: ")
            password = input("PASSWORD: ")
            if username == "admin" and password == "password" :
                print("ACCESS GRANTED")
                break
            else:
                print("WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD COMBO")
                if count<=2:
                    print("TRY AGAIN")
                count += 1
            if count == 3:
                print("NO ATTEMPTS LEFT")
                print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN")
                break
    if (nav) == 2:
        print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN...")
        main()
```

This will keep on trying until the recursion limit is reached.
If you want something that will try forever, do this:

```py
def terminal_login():
    print("=========MENU=========")
    print("1.Login")
    print("2.Exit")
    nav = int(input())
    if (nav) == 1:
        print("=========LOGIN=========")
        print("PLEASE IMPUT THE CORRECT USERNAME AND PASSWORD")
        print("YOU HAVE 3 ATTEMPTS")
        count=0
        while count < 3:
            username = input("USERNAME: ")
            password = input("PASSWORD: ")
            if username == "admin" and password == "password" :
                print("ACCESS GRANTED")
                return True
                break
            else:
                print("WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD COMBO")
                if count<=2:
                    print("TRY AGAIN")
                count += 1
            if count == 3:
                print("NO ATTEMPTS LEFT")
                print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN")
                break
    if (nav) == 2:
        print("TERMINAL SHUTTING DOWN...")
        return False
while True:
    o=terminal_login()
    if o==True:
        break
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to recurse when a simple loop does what you want.